# how to use relative import within python spyder IDE

Tags: python, import, spyder

I got anaconda python and is using the spyder IDE. I'm trying to figure out how can I use relative import for with the run bottom or F5.

suppose I have pkg/A/foo1.py, pkg/A/foo2/py, and foo1.py has "from . import foo2", if I hit run it will report relative import error.

I know how to do it in the command line environment where I can type, e.g. "python -m pkg.A.foo1". How can I do this in spyder IDE?

Thanks
jq

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am stuck with using 
%run -m package_name.module_name

Answer (score -1):

If there is `pkg/A/__init__.py` file i.e., if `pkg.A` is a Python package then `from . import foo2` is correct. It doesn't matter where you write your code in the spyder IDE, notepad, or emacs; the code is the same.

The remaining question is how you **run** Python scripts in spyder IDE.

[**Don’t directly run modules inside packages**](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/) i.e., don't run `python pkg/A/foo1.py`. It leads to Python modules being available under different names. See [Traps for the unwary](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary). Run it as `python -m pkg.A.foo1` from the project directory instead.

Configure the command that is run on `F5` if spyder IDE allows it.

Comment: This answer is not really specific to spyder, we know the commamd line way to do it, the question was about making things work in spyder ide.