# Absolute import module in same package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import

I've simplified my import problems down to this simple base case. Say I have a Python package:

```
mypkg/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
```

a.py contains:

```
def echo(msg):
    return msg
```

b.py contains:

```
from mypkg import a       # possibility 1, doesn't work
#import a                 # possibility 2, works
#from mypkg.a import echo  # import also fails

print(a.echo())
```

Running `python b.py` produces `ImportError: No module named mypkg` on both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.3.5. I have also tried adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` in both cases, same issue.

#### Expected:

I expect possibility 1 to work just fine.

#### Why do I want to do this:

Possibility 2 is less desirable. Hypothetically, the standard library could introduce a package called `a` (unlikely in this case, but you get the idea). While Python 2 searches the [current package first](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), Python 3+ includes absolute import changes so that the standard library is checked first.
No matter what my reason, possibility 1 is supposed to work, no? I could swear I've done it thousands of times before.

Note: If you write a script external to `mypkg`, `from mypkg import a` works without issue.

My question is similar to [python - absolute import for module in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951941/python-absolute-import-for-module-in-the-same-directory#), but the author implies that what I have should be working.

Comment: The absolute path to the same folder is not needed. See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11952026/2886003)  to the cited question.

Comment: related: [how to use relative import within python spyder IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23177615/4279) (see the links in my answer: they apply to the absolute imports too)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`from mypkg import a` is the correct form. Don't run scripts from inside the Python package directory, it makes the same module available using multiple names that may lead to bugs. Run `python -m mypkg.b` from the directory that contains `mypkg` instead.

To be able to run from any directory, `mypkg` should be in pythonpath.

Comment: `python -m mypkg.b` would also work fine if the import was written as a relative import, as in `from . import a` - and this to me seems more elegant as renaming mypkg won't break the import - but seems like relative imports are frowned upon. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D python scripts (ˋ__name__ == '__main__'ˋ) has to use absolute imports.

Comment: Aha makes sense - could you provide me with a refernce where this is discussed?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D "modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports." https://docs.python.org/3.12/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references Though, it does not apply to the case in question: I do NOT get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` with `python -m pkg.script` form, and it is supported by the docs:  "This [relative] import style can be used when referencing modules within a package." https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will not work, because at the moment you call `print(mypkg.a.echo())`, `mypkg` is still loading (`mypkg.__init__` -> `mypkg.b`). This is because Python loads parent modules first. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching

What you can do is wrap `print(mypkg.a.echo())` into a function:

```
def echo():
   mypkg.a.echo()
```

And then:

```
import mypkg.b
mypkg.b.echo()
```

Or even:

```
print(sys.modules['mypkg.a'].echo())
```

Also you can help Python to find your module:

```
import importlib
mypkg.a = importlib.import_module('mypkg.a')
mypkg.a.echo()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you don't have a reference to *mypkg* inside the *mypkg* folder. Look at what Python is doing  when I try to run your example (using the verbose option):

```
# trying /vagrant/mypkg/mypkg.py
```

That's why it can find the module, because it doesn't exist. One hack you could do is to have a file called *mypkg.py* with the line

```
import a
```

but that's just your 2nd possibility above in another jacket. Without knowing what you want to accomplish, I would choose the first example on the [Intra-package Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) text. I would write *b.py* as such:

```
from a import echo

print(echo('message'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(this_dir))

from mypkg import a
print(a.echo())
```

Comment: `sys.path` is a list of strings and not your system's `$PATH`. That said, editing it can still result in breaking libraries importing similarly named modules.