# Multiple relative imports in python 2.7 packages

Tags: python, import, relative-import

I understand there are many SO questions on relative imports. I will document the extent I have tried the solutions therein, but I am still unable to solve my problem.

I have the following directory structure. It's not mine by design but I'm game for modifying things as necessary (forked repo).

```
exp
  main_Exp.py
  kaffe
    __init__.py
    tensorflow
      __init__.py
      network_shape.py
  ResNet
    __init__.py    (*)
    ThreeDMM_shape.py
```

To run the model in this repo, I am to use

`python main_Exp.py input_file.csv`

Inside `main_Exp.py`:

```
sys.path.append('./kaffe')
sys.path.append('./ResNet')
from ThreeDMM_shape import ResNet_101 as resnet101_shape
from ThreeDMM_expr import ResNet_101 as resnet101_expr
```

Inside `ResNet/ThreeDMM_shape.py`:

```
sys.path.append('/home/usc/Desktop/Research/FG18/ExpNet_Code_Release/kaffe/tensorflow')
from network_shape import Network_Shape
```

Ok, so obviously I need to change this hard-coded absolute path. I'd like to do it the right way and not use my own specific path that I happened to install these files to.

---

So I try

```
from ..kaffee.tensorflow import Network_Shape

>>> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

(1) I added `__init__.py` file in the `ResNet` folder (shown with the `(*)`)
(2) I tried running the file as a module: `python -m main_Exp input_file.csv`
(3) I also tried adding `__init__.py` to the top level folder (`exp`), though I believe doing so is nonsense.
(4) Given that the first import was happening using the `kaffe` path that was appended to `sys.path`, I tried changing import to `from .tensorflow.network_shape import Network_Shape`

Same error after all steps.

So I'm not understanding the rules around relative imports and how to reference files in a sane way. I would really appreciate a pointer that helps me understand how to do this, and how to think about such imports in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp` is indeed not a package and won't be made to a package even if you add an init file to it, cause that won't magically add it to the paths python looks for packages. If you do add the `__init__.py` you can then run as `python -m exp.main_Exp input_file.csv` (from `../exp`). This would make python recognize exp as a package and kaffe/ResNet as subpackages. You would need to change imports to `from ResNet.ThreeDMM_shape import ResNet_101 as resnet101_shape` etc.

Edit in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126305/multiple-relative-imports-in-python-2-7-packages/55167225?noredirect=1#comment97082988_55167225): 
Running from the parent dir using the m switch is the recommended way of running the script see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/23540051/281545 (that's for python 3 however it should still apply). If you want to avoid it (it would break hardcoded relative paths for one) you should add exp to sys path (once maybe is enough) then change the imports to absolute ones as in:

```
# main_Exp.py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))) # the exp folder
from ResNet.ThreeDMM_shape import ResNet_101 as resnet101_shape
from ResNet.ThreeDMM_expr import ResNet_101 as resnet101_expr

# ResNet/ThreeDMM_shape.py
from kaffee.tensorflow import Network_Shape
```

Comment: Ok this helps; so as written, `kaffe` is a package, `ResNet` is a package, and if they both just happen to live in the non-package folder `exp` there's no python-related way that they know about each other outside of the package search path, is that right? I hesitate to simply add a whole bunch of folders to the path, but is this simply how it's done?

Comment: I am not sure whether or not this is the best way to structure it all. This way you drop the `sys.append` calls - they are taken care of by python with the `-m` there. Alternatively you would append just `exp` to `sys.path` and then use absolute imports (`from kaffe.tensorflow ...`). By adding just `exp` python will scan it for packages and  discover `kaffe` and `ResNet`. This way it adds`exp.kaffe` and `exp.ResNet`.

Comment: That smelled bad to me too, which is why I didn't want to add more. The code is not mine originally; ideally I want to fix the imports in a way that can be merged back to the upstream repo. That's why I'm also wary of requiring users to run it with `-m`, since that's a breaking change to the current API, so I'm trying to understand python imports more broadly to fix it soundly.