# relative import in python 3.9.5

Tags: python, import, relative-import

My folder structure is as follows

```
./fff
├── __init__.py
├── fg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── settings
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── settings.py
└── obng
    └── test.py
```

I want to import the settings.py inside fg/settings as a module into the test.py

I have added the line

from ..fg.settings import settings

But when I run it, it gives me the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/d/Repos/fff/obng/test.py", line 1, in 
from ..fg.settings import settings
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

This style of relative importing is supported as per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Relative imports can't go above the __main__ package location (or the folder where you started your python process). If you run `test.py`, you can't import stuff from `fg` in a relative fashion.

Comment: If you run `python test.py` you can't use `from ..`. But if you have another .py file under `fff` and `import test` then that will work.

Comment: The only way to bypass this is add path variable, like `sys.path.insert('/mnt/d/Repos/fff/fg')` and then `import fg.setting`

Answer (score 7):

It is a matter of how you run your project - you should run from the parent directory of the top-level package as in

```
$ cd ../fff
$ python -m fff.obng.test # note no py
```

Then relative imports will be resolved correctly. It is an antipattern running a script directly from its folder

Comment: This solved all my problems. It's as if there are 2 worlds when executing code in Python: Module world and file world. When setting your project up with modules, stick to the module way to run things., which also seems easier/more consistent. Would you have a reference for a description of why running a script directly from its folder is an antipattern ?

Comment: Thanks @PaulPM - see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/23540051/281545

Answer (score 6):

Normally you can't use relative imports when you run your python module as main module like `python filename.py` but there is a hack using `__package__` to achieve this. Remember `__package__` is how python resolves relative imports:

1- Create a file called `__init__.py` in your root directory - `fff`. ( I can see that you have it, I mentioned for completeness)

2- Put this code on top of your `test.py` module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and not __package__:
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, <path to parent directory of root directory - fff>)
    __package__ = 'fff.obng'
```

Note: `sys.path` is where python searches for modules to import them.

3- Now place your relative import statement after the code above (inside the if statement, because we don't wanna mess when your `test.py` is being imported) :

```
from ..fg.settings import settings
```

Now you can call you `test.py`, it will run without problem. I don't recommend using these hacks but showing the flexibility of the language and doing exactly what you wanna do in some cases is beneficial.

Other good solutions: Absolute import I think is easier and cleaner than this. In addition take a look at @Mr_and_Mrs_D's answer another good solution would be to run your module with [`-m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) command-line flag.

Comment: Stop advising to use `sys.path` hacks please

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You're right sir, I've added couple of sentences to make people avoid using hacks. I intended to show possible solution and capability of dynamically tweaking stuffs in python. This was the only solution if he wants to run his scripts by file name like `python filename.py`

Comment: I'm a big fan of this answer, please continue advising `sys.path` hacks please!

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports are based on the name of the current module. When running

```sh
python fff/obng/test.py
```

the name of test.py will be `__main__` and the import will not work.

What will work is having another script called "test.py" outside the fff module that imports the fff.obng.test

```
fff_top
├── fff
│   ├── fg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── settings
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── settings.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── obng
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test.py
└── test.py
```

with fff_top/test.py:

```py
import fff.obng.test
```

Then, running the "external" test.py should be ok:

```sh
python fft_top/test.py
```

Alternatively, I would recommend dropping relative imports entirely. One way to do this is using a virtual environment for every package you write, using for example the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) library:

```
python -m venv venv
```

Then, add a setup.py in the root folder with the content:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name="fff", packages=find_packages())
```

and change the imports in `obng/test.py`:

```py
from fff.fg.settings import settings
```

Finally, activate your virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

and install your package in editable mode:

```
pip install -e .
```

Then, after you have completed all the steps above:

```sh
python fff/obng/test.py
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Due to time limitations, I just added the absolute path to the settings.py (./...../fg/settings) to the PYTHONPATH variable and then the import worked as expected. I will try out these implementations as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you could create a symbolic link:

```
$ ln -s ../folder1 mymodules
$ python
>>> import mymodules.myfancymodule as fancy
```