# Why module cannot be found even if I use __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I tried to read how [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) works and use what is suggested, but I still have questions:

If I `cd` to `project` folder and run `python ./test/test1.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'`.

- If I add `print(os.getcwd())` it does print the current directory which is `project`. So, why it cannot find `lib` folder?
- If I `cd` to `project/test`, add `import sys sys.path.append('..')` to the beginning of `test1.py` and then run `python test1.py` it works. But, why I cannot run it from one level above?
- I also tried to add `__init__.py` to `lib` and `test` folders, but I get same error.
- If I try changing to relative path `from .lib.lib1 ...` and run the `test.py` from `project` folder I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` error

What am I doing wrong?

**test1.py**

```
from lib.lib1 import MyClass
```

**Project structure**

```
project
  lib
    lib1.py
    lib2.py
  test
    test1.py # from lib.lib1 import MyClass
   
  main.py
```

Comment: You need to tell python about your packages. This is usually done via the `__init__.py` files you already mentioned. I would expect one in each of your folders lib and test. Finally, you may want to add a setup.py that contains info about both packages (or at least about lib) in the setup function. Then you should be able to install your packages in develop mode to make it available to your interpreter with something like `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script, Python automatically adds (only) "*its*" directory to the `sys.path` which is where it looks for other modules and packages. In your case, by running `python ./test/test1.py`, its directory which is `<rest of the path>/test/` is going to be added to the `sys.path` and that's it.

Now where is the `lib` directory? It is in the `<rest of the path>/project/` directory. But the `<rest of the path>/project/` directory is not in the `sys.path`. Yes it's your current working directory but Python doesn't add your "current directory" to the `sys.path`. Only the script's directory.

The rule is, Check what is inside your `sys.path` and see if the module you're importing is accessible through one of the records inside that list. If it's not, *you need to explicitly add it*.

Why are you facing these kind of issues? Normally you won't(shouldn't?) run the sub modules/packages directly. They supposed to be invoked by the `main.py` module(except for tests though). In that case the `<rest of the path>/project/` directory is in `sys.path` so that all other submodules which use the absolute import statements starting from the root will work properly.

Side note: In the absence of `__init__.py` module, your import statements still work because of the [Implicit Namespace Packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/).

Solution:

Add this at the top of your `test1.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("<rest of the path>/project")
```

And then use this form for import in `test1.py`:

```py
from lib.lib1 import MyClass
```

As you see, you have to add it to all sub-modules which you directly run, Another option is to use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. So instead of writing `sys.path.append....`, run your script like:

```
PYTHONPATH="<rest of the path>/project" python ./test/test1.py
```

Comment: I added `print(sys.path)` to `test1.py` and ran `python3 ./test/test1.py` from root. The `...../project/test` is included in `sys.path`. So, why when I add `from ..lib import lib1` to `test1.py` I get `attempted relative import with no known parent package?` Doesn't `..` mean to go one level up and find `lib` directory? So, since `project/test` is in `sys.path` it should have found it, right?

Comment: @theateist No. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) said that you shouldn't use relative imports when you're running your script as the main script. Although I showed a hack to make it work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302324/13944524) but I do not recommend it. Use absolute import whenever you're running your script as the main module. So `from lib.lib1 import MyClass`. As I mentioned in the answer it doesn't matter where you are in the file system. If you need to access `lib.lib1`, just check `sys.path`...

Comment: @theateist ... Is there any record which can find the `lib` ? Yes there is. You added the absolute path to the `project` directory to the `sys.path` so `lib` can be easily found. No need to go one or two levels up with dots and then import it.

Comment: just to make sure I understood, when I add `sys.path.append('..')` it means to go one level up from the directory the script was run from and NOT from the directory the script is located, right? Meaning, if I cd to `<rest of the path>/A/project` and run `python3 ./test/test1.py` from there, it will look in `<rest of the path>/A` directory and not one level up from the location of the script, meaning in `<rest of the path>/A/project`, right? If the first is correct, then I have to cd to `test` directory and run the `test1.py` from there if I add `sys.path.append('..')`, right?

Comment: @theateist No. you must add `sys.path.append(".")`. Let me explain it this way: Python only sees where the directory of the script is located and add that path to the `sys.path`. Now you're in the root directory, the `os.getcwd()` shows you're in the root directory. Is it added to the `sys.path` ? No because it was not the `test1.py`'s directory. If you want to add the root path to the `sys.path` you should only add `"."` which currently points to your location.