# Python relative import not working even though root package name is being used

Tags: python, relative-import

I've read quite a bit about relative import's tricky aspects (especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-trilli%D0%BEnth-time/14132912#14132912)). However, the following example is still not working.

I have the following project ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/UnittestDiscovery)):

[image: DirectoryTree]

Here's `test_some_unit.py`:

```py
import unittest

from ..util.foo import run_foo


class TestSomeUnit(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_unit(self):
        run_foo()
        print("Unit package")
```

The `integration` side is analogous.

Running discovery from current working directory `UnittestDiscovery`which is the parent of `package`, for the root package `package` produces a relative import error:

```
UnittestDiscovery> python -m unittest discover package
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: integration.test_some_integration (unittest.loader._FailedTest.integration.test_some_integration)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: integration.test_some_integration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 407, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\rodrigobraz\Documents\PyCharmProjects\UnittestDiscovery\package\integration\test_some_integration.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..util.foo import run_foo
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package


======================================================================
ERROR: unit.test_some_unit (unittest.loader._FailedTest.unit.test_some_unit)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: unit.test_some_unit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 407, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\rodrigobraz\Documents\PyCharmProjects\UnittestDiscovery\package\unit\test_some_unit.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..util.foo import run_foo
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relative import in python 3.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300555/relative-import-in-python-3-9-5)
Note that many information regarding relative imports is outdated and does not work with newer Python versions. The anwser you are linking is over 10 years old.

Comment: Thanks, the linked question was useful because it contains a very clear answer by @Mr_and_Mrs_D (who also gave an also useful partial answer in this my own question). However, the linked question does not answer my question (for the same reason @Mr_and_Mrs_D's answer here does not completely answer it) because its answer does not translate to my situation with `unittest`. Like @Mr_and_Mrs_D's says, I would need to tell `unittest` to run tests using the `-m` flag from the directory above `package`, but this does not seem possible.

Comment: @OskarHofmann, also, you mention that relative imports have changed quite a lot in recent versions of Python, and from the description given the 10-year-old question. However, after reading the question you linked I didn't notice any difference between it and the 10-year-old explanation. If you can refer to what they are, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the comment [Python relative import not working even though root package name is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77822594/python-relative-import-not-working-even-though-root-package-name-is-being-used#comment137196269_77822710)

> Thanks. I am running from the directory above package (it's called UnittestDiscovery) so I would expect module test_some_unit to have name `test.unit.test_some_unit`, leading `..util` to refer to `test.util`. Is this reasoning incorrect?

The reasoning is correct (although I don't see any test package) – however probably once the tests are discovered unittest tries to run them from their directory hence you get the error on the top level package – so you should find a way to instruct unittest to run the tests using the `-m` switch, from the parent of the root package as you do. Don't do the `sys.path.append` hack, by all means.

Comment: Sorry, I typed `test` in the comment but I had renamed it and should have been `package`.

Comment: Ah, at first I thought `unittest` would not give me a way to do that, but it does! I will show commands in separate comments for clarity:

Comment: `UnittestDiscovery> python -m unittest discover -t . package`

Comment: where `-t . ` sets the project root directory. Things then work.
For the record, sub-packages can be tested with (for example):

Comment: `UnittestDiscovery> python -m unittest discover -t . package.unit`

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, because you are running your test unit discovery probably from the root of your project, and when it runs your test_some_unit.py, it tries to import the function relatively to the current directory (aka the root of your project), that is why it states that you attempt a relative import beyond the top-level package.

You can either:

1. keep your relative imports and consider that you will always run your unit tests using your command line above from the root of your project, and adapt the code of your test_some_unit.py

   ```
   from util.foo import run_foo
   ```

or

2. (what I recommend) use absolute imports. This way you can both run your unit tests with your command line and by running directly your unit test script.

   ```
   import os.path
   import sys

   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), ".."))
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I am running from the directory *above* `package` (it's called `UnittestDiscovery`) so I would expect module `test_some_unit` to have name `test.unit.test_some_unit`, leading `..util` to refer to `test.util`. Is this reasoning incorrect?

Comment: I've updated the figure and question to reflect this additional information, BTW.

Comment: PS: I renamed `test` to `package` but when writing the comment above forgot to replace.

Comment: It seems like your solution 1 does not use relative imports (even though the beginning of solution 2 makes it sound like solution 1 would be the relative import alternative), while your solution 2 seems targets at supporting relative imports even though it says "use absolute imports".